# Java: 2D array minimum and maximum values

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am working on this program to find minium and maximum values of the variable milesTracker and have been successful for a few tests but it breaks testing it with values {{-5}, {-93}, {-259}}.

Note: I cannot edit anything outside of the commented area, however, I can add more lines anywhere within the commented area.

I'd appreciate the help.

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArraysKeyValue {
   public static void main (String [] args) {
      final int NUM_ROWS = 2;
      final int NUM_COLS = 2;
      int [][] milesTracker = new int[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS];
      int i = 0;
      int j = 0;
      int maxMiles = 0; // Assign with first element in milesTracker before loop
      int minMiles = 0; // Assign with first element in milesTracker before loop

      milesTracker[0][0] = -10;
      milesTracker[0][1] = 20;
      milesTracker[1][0] = 30;
      milesTracker[1][1] = 40;

      // Start of area to be modified
      for(i=0;i<NUM_ROWS;++i){
         for(j=0;j<NUM_COLS;++j){
             if (milesTracker[i][j]<minMiles){
               minMiles = milesTracker[i][j];
            }
             else if (milesTracker[i][j] > maxMiles){
               maxMiles = milesTracker[i][j];
            }
         } 
      }
      // End of area to be modified

      System.out.println("Min miles: " + minMiles);
      System.out.println("Max miles: " + maxMiles);
   }
}
```

Errors:

[image: Errors and Stuff]

Comment: Try for a sec to remove that else instead of `else if (milesTracker[i][j] > maxMiles){` try `if (milesTracker[i][j] > maxMiles){`

Comment: Don't initialize `int minMiles = 0`. Try `int minMiles = Integer.MAX_VALUE`;

Comment: @bradimus it should be MaxValue not min i think

Comment: I removed the else and it still breaks in the same spot. Also, I can't change anything outside of the designated area of modification.

Comment: If the area of modification is inside the double for, them, add a case to pick the first post in the array (0,0) when i==0 and j==0 for min and max `if(i==0&&j==0){ maxMiles = milesTracker[0][0]; minMiles = milesTracker[0][0]; }

Comment: @Aramza You should edit the post adding " can't change anything outside of the designated area of modification" and what area is

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Start of area to be modified
maxMiles = milesTracker[0][0];
minMiles = milesTracker[0][0];

for(i=0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++){
    for(j=0; j < NUM_COLS; j++){
        if (milesTracker[i][j] < minMiles){
            minMiles = milesTracker[i][j];
        }
        else if (milesTracker[i][j] > maxMiles){
            maxMiles = milesTracker[i][j];
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: OP can not edit the initial value of max and min acourding to his comments outside of the designated area

Comment: @ManuelMejias until outer for loop exits minMiles and maxMiles can take temporary values. Aren't they ?

Comment: if you make it so that, max and min take the values of (0,0) inside the double for when i==0 and j==0  i think OP would not complain

Answer (score 0):

You initialize,

```
int maxMiles = 0;
```

Yet you only update `maxMiles`,

```
if(milesTracker[i][j] > maxMiles)
```

while iterating through your array with `{{-5},{-93},{-253}}`, none of those values are greater than `maxMiles == 0`. Thus `maxMiles` is never updated.

Try declaring it arbitrarily within the set

```
int maxMiles = milesTracker[0][0];
```

Then `maxMiles` cannot be out of the set.